# Confused with Wix bootstraper

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I am having trouble understanding wix documentation. I have created a simple installer that allows user to select a destination folder for app. It looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="AppName" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Manufacturer" UpgradeCode="guid">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SetupProjectFeature" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>

    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>

</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="OeeCoach" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
        <Component Id="EntityFramework" Guid="guid">
            <File Id="EntityFramework.dll" Source="../App/bin/Release/EntityFramework.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="MvvmLight.Extras" Guid="guid">
            <File Id="GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4.dll" Source="../App/bin/Release/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Now I need to check for .net 4 and its prerequisites, but I could not understand hot to do this. Documentation says that I need to use Bundle element, but compiler seems to complain when it is together with Product element in same wix file.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrapper is a separate project from your setup project. If you are using Visual Studio, add a new project to your solution and choose Bootstrapper project (instead of Setup project).

Comment: Hi BryanJ, thanks for the response. I came to that conclusion myself yesterday, although I was doing it manually. Is there a UI/wizard support for building bootstrapper project in VS, or it just creates a blank wxs file??

Comment: There is no wizard, you get template to help get you started (like most projects created in VS), but you have to fill in all the details.